# MySQL binlog getting rotated at file size of 479 bytes on RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I created a MySQL RDS instance with 100GB storage. The `max_binlog_size` is default `134217728` bytes. However I see binary logs getting rotated at very small file sizes of `479` bytes.

```
 mysql> show binary logs;
    +----------------------------+-----------+
    | Log_name                   | File_size |
    +----------------------------+-----------+
    | mysql-bin-changelog.000009 |       479 |
    | mysql-bin-changelog.000010 |       422 |
    +----------------------------+-----------+
```

What is the reason?.

Comment: you restart the DB Server ?

Comment: No, it is always rotating at 479 bytes

Comment: have you looked if some staement in the binlog like : **mysqlbinlog PATHTOBINLOG/mysql-bin-changelog.000010**

Comment: I am experiencing something similar with binary logs getting rotated most of the time at 590 bytes and considering that only the latest three binary logs were being retained by default (which made for a very small time to stop and resume the replica operation), I had to increase the retention period as indicated in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql_rds_set_configuration.html#mysql_rds_set_configuration-usage-notes.binlog-retention-hours